# iOS CoreNFC - class "NFTechnologyEvent" not loaded or does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, core-nfc

I'm getting this error when trying to read a NFC tag using an iPhone 7 Plus

> 2017-12-13 14:03:01.522137-0300 nfc[279:9534] [general]  connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc: Exception caught during decoding of received message, dropping incoming message.
>
> Exception: Exception while decoding argument 0 (#2 of invocation):
>
> Exception: decodeObjectForKey: class "NFTechnologyEvent" not loaded or does not exist

I have the proper entitlement (`Near Field Communication Tag Reading`) and `Privacy - NFC Scan Usage Description` setted.

To reproduce it just start a new single view project and replace the default `ViewController` with this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreNFC

class ViewController: UIViewController, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {
    // Reference the NFC session
    private var nfcSession: NFCNDEFReaderSession!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.startScanning()
    }

    func startScanning() {
        // Create the NFC Reader Session when the app starts
        self.nfcSession = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)

        // A custom description that helps users understand how they can use NFC reader mode in your app.
        self.nfcSession?.alertMessage = "Macri Gato"

        self.nfcSession?.begin()
    }

    // Called when the reader-session expired, you invalidated the dialog or accessed an invalidated session
    public func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print("NFC-Session invalidated: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        print("==========================")

        self.startScanning()
    }

    // Called when a new set of NDEF messages is found
    public func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
        print("New NFC Messages (\(messages.count)) detected:")
        print(messages)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before begin nfcSession you have to check NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable true in order to go on session.begin() method.

Also make sure that you add "**Privacy - NFC Scan Usage Description**" into Info.plist

```
@IBAction func beginScanning(_ sender: Any) {
guard NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(
        title: "Scanning Not Supported",
        message: "This device doesn't support tag scanning.",
        preferredStyle: .alert
    )
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}

session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
session?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near the item to learn more about it."
session?.begin()
```

}