# NFCCore iOS problems

Tags: ios, nfc

I develop an app in iOS using NFC, but I obtain always error 202 that means "unexpected error", but Apple don't give any information about this code.

I've:

1. Enable NFC on Developer Apple app page
2. Use Iphone 7 with iOS 11
3. Setted .entitlements key com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats to an array with NDEF
4. Set NFC privacy key to info.plist
5. Write the code to manage NFC (similar to this [iOS CoreNFC - class "NFTechnologyEvent" not loaded or does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798893/ios-corenfc-class-nftechnologyevent-not-loaded-or-does-not-exist/52098223#52098223))

class TPNfcReaderViewController : UIViewController {

```
var nfcSession: NFCNDEFReaderSession!
func startScanning(){
    nfcSession = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main, invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
    nfcSession.alertMessage = "You can hold you NFC-tag to the back-top of your iPhone"
    nfcSession.begin()
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    startScanning()
}
```

extension TPNfcReaderViewController : NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {

```
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error reading NFC: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    //session.invalidate()
    //self.startScanning()
}
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
    //Never called
}
```

}

But I obtain always

```
    connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc: Exception caught during decoding of received message, dropping incoming message.
Exception: Exception while decoding argument 0 (#2 of invocation):
Exception: decodeObjectForKey: class "NFTechnologyEvent" not loaded or does not exist
```

Have you any suggestion?

Comment: Could you post your code, and check if `NFCNDEFReaderSession .readingAvailable()` returns true at least?

Comment: Added, sorry for formatting but StackOverflow not format it. readingAvailable return true

Comment: Maybe I have an update; I've tried my iOS app with NFC of a bluetooth speaker and it recognize that speaker. So I've seen what prints this tag, and in avalaible technologies I see "Ndef, NfcA". Instead, with my Android app, I see "IsoDep, NfcA". So the other question now is how to write Ndef message in android? :)

Answer (score 0):

Before call session.begin() method, you have to check NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable true.

Also make sure that you add "Privacy - NFC Scan Usage Description" into Info.plist

Please check the sample code from apple docs below. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app